# how to call the Thread repeatedly?

Tags: c#, multithreading

i need to call thread for every 3 sec in my application. From thread i need to call a function. how can i do this in c#? i need to call that thread only because  when i call it thread it will not affect my process?. In that function i am going to check if particular process going on or not?

how to call method in System.timers timer ?

Comment: You can't call threads. You call methods. What do you really want to do?

Comment: Same function in every 3 sec?

Comment: yes i need to start new thread

Comment: @ratty: instead of telling us what you think you need to do, how about telling us what you actually *want* to do? (Instead of telling us "I need to start threads", tell us "I want to play a sound every 3 seconds"). It would make the question easier to answer in a way that helps you most.

Comment: yes i like to that in that function something like  Martinho Fernandes said

Comment: Then you could run a parallel thread and call `Thread.Sleep(3000);` between plays of the sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use a Timer rather than a Thread.

If this is a GUI application then you'll want the System.Windows.Forms.Timer if its not then you could use Sytem.Timers.Timer.